# hyperlink excel doesn't work in different computer

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have an excel sheet whereby it links with the documents in my computer using hyperlink. how should i make it accessible for other computers when i give them the excel sheet without giving the folder that stores the document?

hyperlink(file location, display name)

Comment: Do they have access to the file? (your computer) If not, then it's not possible...

Comment: @DirkReichel, yup. they have to access the particular file when they click the hyperlink without me sending one whole bulk of file.

Comment: The need to be able to access it from wherever they open the file... if you know the path to the file from an extern  source, you simply need to replace the path in the workbook